# Rails LoadError; undefined symbol: cNArray when using GSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gsl

I'm trying to use the gsl gem in a rails project. The gemfile contains:

```
gem 'gsl', '~> 1.15'
```

and when the following code is ran

```
gsl-config --version
```

the version appearing is

```
1.15
```

when I try to run a rake file the following message appears:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: /home/ultimate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@rails3/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/gsl-1.16.0.6/gsl_native.so: undefined symbol: cNArray
```

Tried installing different versions of the gsl library and continue to have the same issue.

Comment: did you see this? https://github.com/blackwinter/rb-gsl/issues/4

Comment: It appears that it could be the issue, where do I access to the extconf.rb file so I can change it and test if it works?

Comment: I cannot find the extconf.rb as explained in http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/

Comment: I found the extconf.rb (http://pastebin.com/4Cd7swQP) commented out the three lines including narray at the end of the file. Then I ran ruby extconf.rb followed by make and no changes were obtained.

Comment: This error should not appear in the latest version of gsl (2.1). Could you please check it with that? It has been made such that it does not depend on narray anymore.